# How do I post to foreign key from Users to another Table in Asp.Net web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I have a users table with a 'UserId' column, this 'UserId' is foreign key to another table 'Calendar Table'. How do I send a post method from the calendar controller to post UserId from Users Table to Calendar Table?

**dbo.calendar**

```
[FileLength]           BIGINT         NOT NULL,
[CreationTime]         DATETIME       NOT NULL,
[LastUpdatedOn]        DATETIME       NULL,
[UserId]               NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[ApplicationUser_Id]   NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.CalendarTables] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.CalendarTables_dbo.User_ApplicationUser_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicationUser_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.CalendarTables_dbo.User_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
```

**dbo.users**

```
[LockoutEnabled]       BIT            NOT NULL,
[AccessFailedCount]    INT            NOT NULL,
[UserName]             NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
[UserId]               NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

**Calendar Controller**

```
// POST api/value
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ResponseType(typeof(CalendarTable))]

    public IHttpActionResult PostCalendar(CalendarTable calendarTable)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.CalendarTables.Add(calendarTable);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = calendarTable.Id }, calendarTable);
    }
```

I just need a method or a way to post a particular users 'UserId' from User Table to the 'UserId' of Calendar Table when a post request is made.

Comment: Where you looking for `UserId`? It's came from request or you get current user by `this.User.Identity.Name` in controller action and try to find that `UserId` in the table `dbo.users`?

Comment: @AlexanderYakushev thanks. I just need a method to be able to post UserId to calendar table from users table